# To shutdown the apache tomcat 7, which process is the best one killing or shutdown ? and why?

Tags: linux, tomcat7

shoutdown : sh shutdown.sh

```
    or
```

killing tomcat
ps -eaf | grep tomcat

kill -9 number

which one is best?

Comment: If Tomcat is installed as a service, try `/etc/init.d/tomcat stop` (might be *tomcat7* instead).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to shutdown tomact is by using shutdown script. But many people face issues with it and end up doing the second option that you mentioned.

Shutdown script works properly only if the scripts that will be touched during shutdown process are either :

1. owned by the user.
2. owned by the PRIMARY group of the user

this will not work if the user belongs in secondary groups.

Some other issues are mentioned here : 
https://serverfault.com/questions/115867/tomcat-shudown-does-not-kill-process

In case you have to choose later one, you can use the below mentioned script to make it as a single command. Just put in inside a script and run it whenever you want to kill running tomcat.

```
#Finds the tomcat process id
ps aux | grep tomcat | grep JavaVirtualMachines | awk -F  " " '{print $2}' > tomcatProcessID

#Kills the process id returned from above mentioned command.
kill -9 `cat tomcatProcessID` && tput setaf 3 && echo "Tomcat killed Successfully" ;rm -rf tomcatProcessID

#Not a mandatory command.
#Used to show all the remaining processes with 'tomcat' keyword in it.
#To inform on the console that the tomcat (running ess or indexer) is killed.
ps aux | grep tomcat | grep -v grep | grep -v killtomcat
```